# Rounding cell value to nearest thousand in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been trying to round a cell value up or down to the nearest thousand but can't get it to work. I'm trying to calculate my hourly rate based on the current exchange rate from USD to VND But if the resulting total is something like 22,325 then it should round down to 22,000 and likewise if the hundreds are 500 or more it should round up to 23,000

[image: Calculation sample]

So where the hourly rate says 527,325 it should round down to 527,000. The cell already contains a formula to multiply the the current exchange rate by the USD.

Answer (score 11):

Using the `ROUND` function:

`=ROUND(A1,-3)`

Where A1 is the cell containing the number you wish to round.
The negative number specifies digits to the ***left*** of the decimal point to replace with zeros (the number of zeros at the end of the number).

Like so:

`=ROUND( 34528, -3 ) = 35000`

As for the OP's example:

`=ROUND( 22325, -3 ) = 22000`

The OP also stated:

> likewise if the hundreds are 500 or more it should round up to 23,000

`=ROUND( 22500, -3 ) = 23000`

[image: ROUND Function]

See [**ROUND Function** Office support](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/ROUND-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this:

```
=MROUND(A1,1000)
```

This should give you what you want.

Comment: This one also just makes more sense from a syntax perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked specifically for a formula that when it 'says 527,325 it should ***round down*** to 527,000'. For this you would need the [FLOOR¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FLOOR-function-14BB497C-24F2-4E04-B327-B0B4DE5A8886) or [ROUNDDOWN¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDDOWN-function-2EC94C73-241F-4B01-8C6F-17E6D7968F53).

```
=FLOOR(A1, 1000)
=ROUNDDOWN(A1, -3)
```

There is also leaving the number alone but formatting with a custom number format of `0, K` but this does not round down. If the number was 527,501 it would display `528 K` not `527 K`.

[image: FLOOR and ROUNDDOWN, Custom Number Formatting]

¹ <sub>The counterparts to FLOOR and ROUNDDOWN are the [CEILING function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CEILING-function-0A5CD7C8-0720-4F0A-BD2C-C943E510899F) and [ROUNDUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-F8BC9B23-E795-47DB-8703-DB171D0C42A7).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1000, then round, then multiply by 1000.
The formula for rounding `A1` in this way would be:

```
=ROUND(A1/1000)*1000
```

If a formula already exists in the `A1` cell, just replace the `A1` with the new formula in the upper expression.